# How do I print command line arguments vertically?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know how to print them backwards, forwards, etc. However, I am having trouble printing something off the command line vertically. Can anyone explain?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int j;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        char *tmp = argv[i];
        int len = strlen(argv[i]);
        for(j = len-1; j > -1; --j)
            printf("%c",tmp[j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have for printing something from the command line backwards, but how would I make it print vertically?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by vertically? Please describe more fully, and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I edited it to show what I have.

Comment: The code you posted prints the arguments backwards, but horizontally. The console can only print horizontally, so you must "transpose" your logic, i.e. switch rows and columns access: In the first line print the first letter of all arguments, in the second, print the second letters of the strings. You must of course make sure that the string has as many letters as the columns you print for each string.

Comment: @DrakeRowland could you give an example of some command line arguments and how you want them printed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to have something like

```
a a a a
r r r r
g g g g
1 2 3 4
```

so the idea would be on the first line to print the first char of each arg, the on the second line the next char, until the end

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int j;
    int i = 0;
    int argsLength[argc];
    int maxLength = 0;

    // get lengths or args
    for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++)
    {
        argsLength[i] = strlen(argv[i+1]);
        if(argsLength[i]>maxLength) {maxLength = argsLength[i];}
    }
    for (i=0;i<maxLength;i++) 
    {
        for(j=0;j<argc-1;j++) {
            if(argsLength[j]<i) {
                printf("%c ",argv[j+1][i]);
            }else{
                printf("  "); // put a blank when not char should be printed
            }
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```